# Creating an object viewer JSON tree from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, tree

I am using [this tool](http://www.easyjstree.com/) to create a JSON tree.

My goal is to create an object viewer from the tree.

I get JSON data from an external method which has an OOP structure, meaning it has custom elements. These custom elements have types and methods. The methods have arguments.

Also, to keep the hiearchy, each element has a "children" attribute which contains children classes.

The tool does just fine, because it binds itself to the "children" attribute, and displays it a level lower.

However, I also want to show the types, methods and arguments.

Right now, the solution I came up with is to iterate through every field and if it has nested elements, place it into the children attribute.

The problem is it seems that such method takes a lot of processing and slows down the program.

Is my approach wrong and is it better to adjust the library to accept more than one children attribute? Or is there another approach that I should take?